# How do I delete my Windows partition?

Tags: partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu and it is great.  However, I installed in beside the Windows Vista OS.  I now want to remove Windows in an effort to improve performance.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Removing Vista will not improve performance in any way you'll only get back whatever space Vista is using. Boot from a livesub/cd and delete the Vista partition.

Comment: If Vista isn't mounted, you don't have to boot from a Live CD. You can just use GParted to remove the partition. You can find GParted in Synaptic Package Manager, Ubuntu Software Center, or run 'sudo apt-get install gparted' from the command line. Uri is right, though - removing Vista will not improve performance under most circumstances.

Comment: Consider marking an answer or closing/deleting?

Answer (score 2):

Or you could delete the Windows partition and dedicate part of that free space as a swap partition (useful depending on what the specs to your machine are) and the other portion for extra space as another Linux partition for storing files on.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Ubuntu in a separate partition ("normal" way), just boot Ubuntu and use `gparted` (you can install it from software center) and delete the Vista Partition.

If you installed in the same partition (wubi) I think you'll have to delete the whole partition and reinstall Ubuntu from a live CD.

Obs: removing Vista will not improve performance unless you are very short on HD free space.